# What's causing inadvertent "leave page" commands when typing in browser window?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, firefox

An annoying thing mostly, but occasionally results in data loss. It happens when I am typing - as I am now - in a browser window in Firefox on my MacBook Pro (2016, Mojave 10.14.6).

When I'm typing on a SE site, I get a *warning*, asking for confirmation that I want to leave the page:

[image]

This is the same warning you'll get if you hit the "Back" button in Firefox after typing in a form that you've not yet posted. If I get the warning, obviously I select `Stay on Page`, and return to my work. But sometimes, I don't get the warning (or it happens in a flash); **this** is when I lose my data. The tab I'm typing in 'backs up' to the previous page instantly. When I go forward, the work/data I've entered is gone.

I've checked my touchpad settings & find nothing other than `Swipe between pages` that seems suspect. I disabled `Swipe between pages` over a year ago with no apparent effect.

[Firefox also has some built-in shortcuts](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly), but they don't look like suspects either:

[image]

I'm not a touch typist. The heels of my hands rest on either side of the touchpad while typing. I don't believe I am accidentally typing `command + ←`.

What is causing this? More importantly, how do I stop it? Is there any way to recover the data, or is it truly "lost"?

Comment: You talk about SE sites giving the warning but then say *"But sometimes, I don't get the warning"*.  Are you asking about the same SE sites or saying some sites do it and some don't?  I always assumed giving the warning was up to the specific website as some do (on some fields) and some don't.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply - I lost track of your comment. I've edited my question in an effort to eliminate the confusion. But if it's still unclear, please advise.

Comment: If you're not in a text box, for instance and you press the backspace key, it will attempt to navigate back.  If you have pending items like text in a form, you'll get that message.  This happens when you inadvertently move your cursor from the form to another element (like brushing your hand against the track pad, for instance).  This can also happen if the page is automatically refreshed with items still pending in forms.

Comment: @Allan: I don't get a "backup" when I move the cursor to another element on the page. I've tried many times to identify a track pad *gesture* that causes this, but haven't discovered anything. But yes, a `Reload` (`command`-`R`) zaps the text box input without warning. I'll put that on my "watch list" - thanks.

Comment: not backup, but back *space*.  It's not a gesture I'm referring to...it's moving out of the form input box by accident, then pressing something like backspace.  As far as refresh, some sites *auto* refresh.  Just save often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been nearly 2.5 years since I asked this question, and I have just now found the answer.

The "culprit" was the ***Touch Bar*** - more specifically, the setting on my touch bar. And full disclosure: this probably has something to do with my awful 4-finger typing style (evolved from 2-finger).

I **never use** the Touch Bar, except to change display & keyboard lighting. I **never pay attention to it** as I've long-regarded it as *brain~dead masquerding as innovation*. But I finally noticed that there was an odd array of controls displayed while typing in a comment box on SE, and the control on the left looked like this: <kbd><</kbd>; i.e. the browser's "back button". The ring finger on my left hand will brush against this control occasionally, and I am suddenly on the previous (or 2-5 previous) pages.

One "solution" is illustrated in the ss below: From the `System Preferences Panel`, `Keyboard` widget, change the `Touch Bar Display` from `App Controls` to `Fn Controls`. A far better solution IMHO is to disable the Touch Bar entirely, but unfortunately - as with `Siri` - Apple refuses their customers the ability to disable their skanky innovations :P

[image: Touch Bar Default Setting]